# What does this line mean in Sorting Algo(Bubble example)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, range, bubble-sort

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(array)-1,0,-1):
        print(i)
        for j in range(i):
            print(j)
            if array[j]>array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                swapped= True
        if swapped:
            swapped=False
        else:
            break
    print(array)

bubbleSort([5, 2, 1, 3])
```

How should I interpret this line: `for i in range(len(array)-1,0,-1)`? I'm particularly confused about the need for the `0` and `-1` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line has a couple of things happening, which I will give simplified explanations of (I'm assuming this code is written in Python).

First, `for i in iterable` will loop through `iterable`, meaning the code in the for loop will repeat as many times as there are elements in `iterable`, which could be an array, a list, a string etc, and each time it loops, `i` will be the next element of `iterable`, starting with the first. For example, `for i in [1, 2, 3]` will loop 3 times; the first time, `i` will be equal to 1; the second, 2, etc.

Next, the `range` function produces an iterable that is a range of numbers, for example from 0-9. With a single argument, `range` will produce a range from 0 to that number, but stopping just before it, e.g. `range(5)` will give you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Thus if you were to use `for i in range(5)`, your code would repeat 5 times, with i incrementing from 0 to 4.

With two arguments, the range will start at the first and stop before the second, which must be greater than the first. For example, `range(3, 8)` would give you `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. `range(8, 3)`, however, will not work, as the start number is greater than the stop number. This means you cannot count down with only 2 arguments.

The third optional argument for `range` is the step size; how much you want the numbers to increase *or decrease* by each step. For example, `range(0, 10, 2)` will give you the output `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`, stopping before 10. Here is where you can produce a descending range, by setting the step argument to a negative number. `range(10, 0, -2)` will give you `[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]`, again stopping before the second argument, and `range(10, 0, -1)` will give you the full `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Finally, the `len(iterable)` function will give you the length of whatever you give it, or the number of items contained in say a list. For example `len("Hello!")` will give you 6, and `len([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` will give you 5.

Putting this all together, the line `for i in range(len(array)-1, 0, -1)` will do the following:

- the code will repeat as many times as there are items in a list, with i taking on each value in the list
- that list is a range of numbers
- that start number of the range is the length of `array` minus one
- the end of the range is 0
- the range is descending, with a step size of -1

Thus if `array` were `["fish", "banana", "pineapple", "onion"]`, `len(array)` will return 4, so you will have `for i in range(3, 0, -1)`, which will loop 3 times, with `i` being 3, then 2, then 1.

This was a rather simplified answer, so I suggest you find some tutorials on any functions you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! that explains a lot of confusion! I'm currently struggling to grasp.